# How to filter certain values of numbers from a string and return the rest

Tags: java

I need to create a method that takes a string as an input, like "I have 2456 balloons in 37 wilderness" and if n is set to 3 and "more" is set to false, the method would return "I have 2 balloons in wilderness". If more was set to true, it would return "I have 456 balloons in 7 wilderness"

I have been playing around with the filtering part quite a bit, but I don't know how to put the rest of this method together. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        List<Integer> lst= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //Take user input any number of times based on your condition.

        System.out.println("Please enter a number :");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int i= sc.nextInt();
        if(i==0 || i==1 || i==2 ||i==3)
        {
            lst.add(i);
        }
        //Go back
    }
}
```

Or I could use something like this:

```
int input;
do {
    input = sc.nextInt();
} while (input < 0 || input > 3);
```

I'm pretty new to Java, so progress on this task has been slow

How can I get this method to save the letters and filter numbers depending on the two values (a number and true/false for more)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with explanation.
Take note that we used a very straightforward approach but a lot of validations are still needed. Also, there are shorter solutions but this is the one I wrote so that it's clearer for people new in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
    String strInput = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter n: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Do you want more? (Y/N)");
    char more = sc.next().charAt(0);

    String result = "";

    // Loop through all the characters in the String
    for(char c : strInput.toCharArray()) {

        // Check if the character is a number
        // If not, just append to our result string
        if(!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            result += c;
        } else {
            // Converts character to the number equivalent value
            int numValue = Character.getNumericValue(c);

            // If more is 'Y', we check if it's greater than the number and append
            // else if more is 'N', we check if the value is less than n then append.
            // Otherwise, do nothing.
            if (more == 'Y' && numValue > n) {
                result += c;
            } else if (more == 'N' && numValue < n) {
                result += c;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Do you know why this method does not keep numbers that are more than yes or less than when more = n when result is printed? This does a fantastic job stripping out the numbers